# CellList GWT CSS Style

Tags: css, gwt

I created a CellList in my entry point. Now I want to style it.( Changing the color of selected cell from blue to dark black )

In my knowledge, I only need to override the style of cellList, choose the selected one and change the background color (and then save inside the module.css)

So this is what I came with.

```
@sprite .cellListSelectedItem {
/*gwt-image: 'cellListSelectedBackground';*/
/*BEFORE : background-color: #628cd5;*/
background-color: #2D2D2D;
color: white;
height: auto;
overflow: visible;
}
```

However everytime I select a cell, it still displaying old color (#628cd5). Anything I did wrong?

And oh yes, I cleaned the project and restarted the server-and also clear browser cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell GWT to use the new styles -- simply adding them to your module CSS file isn't going to be enough:

```
table = new CellTable<FooType>(12,
    CellTableResources.INSTANCE, keyProvider);
```

CellTableResources.INSTANCE should be a Resource bundle instance that extends the CellTable Resource bundle. Something like:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.resources.client.ImageResource;
import com.google.gwt.resources.client.ImageResource.ImageOptions;
import com.google.gwt.resources.client.ImageResource.RepeatStyle;
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellTable;
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellTable.Style;

public interface CellTableResources extends CellTable.Resources {

  public static CellTableResources INSTANCE = GWT.create(CellTableResources.class);

  @Source("footer_bg.png")
  @ImageOptions(repeatStyle = RepeatStyle.Both, flipRtl = true)
  ImageResource cellTableFooterBackground();

  @Source("header.png")
  @ImageOptions(repeatStyle = RepeatStyle.Horizontal, flipRtl = true)
  ImageResource cellTableHeaderBackground();

  @Source("table_head_bg_left.png")
  @ImageOptions(repeatStyle = RepeatStyle.None, flipRtl = true)
  ImageResource cellTableHeaderFirstColumnBackground();

  @Source("table_head_bg_right.png")
  @ImageOptions(repeatStyle = RepeatStyle.None, flipRtl = true)
  ImageResource cellTableHeaderLastColumnBackground();

  @Source(CellTableStyle.DEFAULT_CSS)
  Style cellTableStyle();
}
```

And then of course the same sort of thing for CellTableStyle:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellTable;

public interface CellTableStyle extends CellTable.Style {

   String DEFAULT_CSS = "path/to/your/new/CellTable.css";

   String cellTableCell();

   // ....

}
```